# Socket.io with RESTful API

Tags: node.js, rest, sockets, socket.io, restful-architecture

I'm making a RESTful API in `Node.js`, and I would like the client side apps to be updated as soon as a message is created in the database through a `POST` request. So I decided to use `Socket.io`.

Here is my `server.js` code:

```
import http from "http";
import https from "https";

http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1024;
https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1024;

let app = require("express")();
let server = http.Server(app);
let io = require('./lib/sockets').listen(server)

//setup Database
let Database = require("./util/Database").init()

import { version } from "../config/version.json";

app.disable("x-powered-by");

import bodyParser from "body-parser";
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

import routes from "./app/routes";
routes(app);

server.listen(ENV.NODE_PORT);

console.log(
  "server pid %s listening on port %s in %s mode",
  process.pid,
  ENV.NODE_PORT,
  ENV.NODE_ENV
);
```

Here is my `./ib/sockets` file:

```
module.exports.listen = function(app){
  let io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('newMessage', function(messageData) {
      socket.emit('addMessage', messageData);
    })
  });

  return io
}
```

Here is my `./app/routes` file:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  //API messages
  app.post('/api/messages/', require('./api/messages/create'));
  app.get('/api/messages/', require('./api/messages/index'));
}
```

And here is part of my `./app/api/messages/create` file:

```
module.exports = function(req, res) {
  let token = req.headers['bearer-authorization'];
  let tokenSecret = ENV.API_SECRET;
  let decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret);
  let userId = decodedToken.userId;
  let messageType = req.body.messageType;
  let messageText = req.body.messageText;
  let targetGroupIds = req.body.targetGroupIds
  let targetCommitteeIds = req.body.targetCommitteeIds

  let insertMessageId;

  createMessage(userId, messageType, messageText)
    .then(createMessageResult => {
      insertMessageId = createMessageResult.insertId;
      linkMessageToGroupsAndCommittees(insertMessageId, targetGroupIds, targetCommitteeIds);
    })
    .then(linkMessageToGroupsAndCommitteesResult => getNewMessage(insertMessageId))
    .then(formatJSON)
    .then(send.success(res))
    .catch(send.failure(res));
};
```

Now my question is, how can I make it so that when a new message is created, I can call something like `socket.emit('addMessage', {messageAdded: true})` in my `./app/api/messages/create` file?

Comment: Extend the EventEmmiiter you can do anything with that

Comment: I once wanted something similar on one of my project. So, I created this module https://github.com/anand-io/socket.io-router. I did not publish it in npm though. Try and let me know.